# Openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalcharacterError

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have the following python code to write processed words into excel file. The words are about 7729

```
From openpyxl import *
book=Workbook ()
sheet=book.active
sheet.title="test"
for x in range (7729):
    sheet.cell (row=1,column=x+1).value=x
book.save ('test.xlsx')
```

This is the what the code I used looks like, but when I run it, it gives me an error that says

```
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError
```

This is my first time using this module, I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: what is your `.value=` content ?

Comment: I am sorry I forget to right the value

Comment: can you share the outcome of this `print (sys.getdefaultencoding())` ?

Comment: the encoding is utf-8

Comment: please add your python version as well it will help people to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am using python 3.6.

Comment: `exception openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError`
Reason : The data submitted which cannot be used directly in Excel files. It must be removed or escaped. so the issue is some how with your data i.e ur `x` value

Comment: The data is a string, specifically a bunch of english letters.

Comment: that must be the issue then, you need to either escape data or try to forcefully encode it with utf-8 and ignore errors if you can live without unprintable chars in your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**
This code works for me .

```
from openpyxl import *
book=Workbook ()
sheet=book.active
sheet.title="test"
x = 0
with open("temp.txt") as myfile :
    text = myfile.readline()
    while text !="":
            sheet.cell (row=1,column=x+1).value=str(text).encode("ascii",errors="ignore")
            x+=1
            text = myfile.readline()

book.save ('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: In the real program x is a string what should I do for that, should I remove the int function and use the above

Comment: Thank you so much but it seems this din't work. If this helps when I do like sheet ['A1']=1 or sheet ['A1']='hi' works.

Comment: can i see your sample data please ? and they way you are reading that data  from the source ?

Comment: 'Kitaabota', 'seenaa', 'yesuus',and yes i am reading it from a source and the source is a txt file.

Comment: can i see the code you are using to read the text file and exact one line for text file. that will  help me to reproduce the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169038/discussion-between-hilea-and-toheedniaz).

Answer (score 20):

`openpyxl` comes with an illegal characters regular expression, ready for you to use. Presuming you're happy to simply remove these characters, you can do:

```
import re
from openpyxl.cell.cell import ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE
from openpyxl import *

book=Workbook ()
sheet=book.active
sheet.title="test"
for x in range (7729):
   sheet.cell (row=1,column=x+1).value = ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE.sub(r'',x)
book.save ('test.xlsx')
```

To speed it up, you could put the original cell value assignment inside a try/except and only run the re substitution when an `openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError` is caught.

Source: https://www.programmersought.com/article/43315246046/

Answer (score 8):

I faced similar issue and found out that it is because of \xa1 character which is hex value of ascii 26 (SUB). Openpyxl is not allowing to write such characters (ascii code < 32). I tried [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) library without any issue it worte this character in xlsx file.

Answer (score 1):

The best easy solution is to install Xlwriter.

pip install XlsxWriter

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add the value for cell `sheet.cell (row=1,column=x+1).value =`

Try like this

```
from openpyxl import *
book = Workbook ()
sheet = book.active
sheet.title = "test"
for x in range (7):
    sheet.cell (row=1,column=x+1).value = "Hello"
book.save ('test.xlsx')
```