# How to solve the problem of illegal characters when crawling GitHub issues' body?

Tags: python, github-api

I use GitHubAPI to crawl GitHub issues. But due to different country's languages or other special characters, my codes always stop working because of illegal characters. I tried two solutions, but these two will still report errors. This is my code:

```
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']
Body = repo_dict['body']
```

solution 1:

```
Body = ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE.sub(r'', Body)
```

it will reports: *TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object*

solution 2:

```
Body = str(repo_dict['body']).encode('utf-8')
```

it will reports:*raise IllegalCharacterError*
*openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError*

I get an error when I crawl to this issue, but I don't know where is the illegal character?
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3651
and
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1376
The issue below can find a illegal character.

Comment: If I use 'Body =(repo_dict['body']).encode('utf-8')', it will report 'Attribute Error，'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'.'

Comment: what is an "illegal character"....?

Comment: Can you provide a sample from `repo_dict['body']`?

Comment: when you use `string.encode()` it defaults the error argument to `strict` which throws an exception. Does `string.encode('utf8', 'replace')` work? -- edit: I googled it and that was the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844925/openpyxl-utils-exceptions-illegalcharactererror

Comment: May be some characters like  [\000-\010]|[\013-\014]|[\016-\037], because 'ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE' can avoid some errors.

Comment: A more complete example of the code you're using to illustrate this problem might help others provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the codes below to ignore this error, it's working:

```
Body = repo_dict['body']
try:
    Body = ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE.sub(r'', Body)
except:
    print("ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS..")
    Body = "ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS"
```